# How to use pg_get_viewdef(view_oid) to get a view definition?

Tags: postgresql

Looking at the documentation for [System Catalog Info Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) I see that `pg_get_viewdef(view_name)` is deprecated in favour of `pg_get_viewdef(view_oid)`, which better matches how I am getting the functions, and when I write code I prefer not to use something that is deprecated where possible.

I see no `oid` value for views, so the question is how would I get the `oid` value for a view?

PS: Yes I know that I can simply get the `definition` column from `pg_catalog.pg_views`, or I could use `pg_get_viewdef(view_name)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the name to a `regclass` which is compatible with an OID

```
select pg_get_viewdef('view_name'::regclass);
```

If you want to get the actual name from a column, you should use the `format()` function to properly deal with identifiers that need quoting.

```
select format('%I.%I', schemaname, viewname)
from pg_views;
```

will generate such a fully qualified name. The result of that can be passed to `pg_get_viewdef()` if you cast it to `regclass`

```
select pg_get_viewdef(format('%I.%I', schemaname, viewname)::regclass)
from pg_views;
```

This will however return exactly the same result as you can see in the column `pg_views.definition` because `pg_views` uses `pg_get_viewdef()` internally as you can verify for yourself:

```
select pg_get_viewdef('pg_catalog.pg_views'::regclass);
```

Comment: Thanks, except when testing I found that `view_name` should be `viewname` and not in quotes, as it is not a string value but a field reference (I can't edit your answer because "Edits must be at least 6 characters").

Comment: @Duncanmoo: I assumed "view_name" was a dummy value for your actual view name. If you are retrieving from `pg_views` then why don't you just use the content of the column `definition`?

Comment: Got it, your example above is an actual view's name. Per the question I know I can get the `definition` column, I really wanted to understand the use of `pg_get_viewdef(view_oid)`.

Comment: @Duncanmoo: well, there is no much to understand, you just need to pass an `oid` value that references a view name. Casting a string to `regclass` is one way of doing it. Getting the `oid` from `pg_class` is another.